# Java 8 streams: Shorthand for myList.stream().map(Foo::bar).collect(Collectors.toList())

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Is there a common shorthand for the following? External dependencies like Guava welcome.

```
myList.stream().map(Foo::bar).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If I had to implement it, it'd be something like:

```
static <T, U> List<U> mapApply(List<T> list, Function<T, U> function) {
    return list.stream().map(function).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Is there one that works for any Iterable? If not, how would I write one? I started thinking about it like this:

```
static <T, U, V extends Iterable> V<U> mapApply(V<T> iterable, Function<T, U> function) {
    return iterable.stream().map(function).collect(???);
}
```

Comment: I am not aware of any shortcut inside the vanilla JDK.

Comment: Generics can't have generics in Java (```V<U>``` is invalid). I would love to have this too!

Comment: You can not collect into a random `Iterable`, the thing you are collecting into has to support methods like `add` and stuff like that. You could accept any `Collection` and then do `Collectors.toCollection` or just accept a `Collector` instead which would be fully customizable then.

Comment: I see, thanks. Anyway, one that works for just Lists and Sets would more than cover my cases. I feel like it must exist, but having trouble finding it in any libraries I work with. In Mathematica it's a first class citizen as the operator, `/@`.

Comment: I think that any solution general enough to look like your second `mapApply` method would probably have only marginal advantage over just writing the stream/map/collect.

Comment: You can not guaranty that the result has the same type as the input. What if the input is an `EnumSet<Thread.State>` and the mapping function `Thread.State::toString`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case `Foo::bar` returns an instance of `Foo` again, ie. you need to transform `T` into `T` again, then you can use [`List::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) which uses `UnaryOperator<T>`, therefore each item is replaced by one of a same type. This solution mutates the original list.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("John", "Mark", "Pepe");
list.replaceAll(s -> "hello " + s);
```

If you want to transform `T` into `R`, all you can do is to either use your current solution with a sequence of `stream()` -> `map()` -> `collect()` method calls  or a simple iteration.

A static method wrapping this would do the same as well. Note that you cannot create a `Stream` from both `Collection` and `Iterable` using the same way. Feel free to pass also your custom `Collector`.

- `T` is a generic type of an input `Collection` or `Iterable`.
- `R` is a generic type of the mapping function result (mapping from `T` to `R`)

**From `Collection<T>`**

```
List<Bar> listBarFromCollection = mapApply(collectionFoo, Foo::bar, Collectors.toList());
```

```
static <T, R> List<R> mapApply(Collection<T> collection, Function<T, R> function) {
    return collection.stream()
        .map(function)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**From `Iterable<T>`**

```
List<Bar> listBarFromIterable = mapApply(iterableFoo, Foo::bar, Collectors.toList());
```

```
static <T, R> List<R> mapApply(Iterable<T> iterable, Function<T, R> function) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
        .map(function)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

**... with a `Collector`**:

If you want to pass a custom `Collector`, it would be `Collector<R, ?, U> collector` and the return type of the method `U` instead of `List<R>`. As @Holger pointed out, passing a `Collector` to a method would not much differ from calling an actual `stream()` -> `map()` -> `collect()`.

Comment: You don’t need the collection specific variants when you have the iterable variants. Whether I’d create these methods in a project, depends on how often I needed them there. I’d not create yet-another-utility-library for them.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the method like this:

```
public class StreamShorthandUtil {
    
    public static <T, U, V extends Collection<T>, W> W mapApply(V in, Function<T, U> function, Collector<U, ?, W> collector) {
        return in.stream().map(function).collect(collector);
    }

    // main class for testing
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> numbersAsString = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
        List<Integer> numbers = mapApply(numbersAsString, Integer::parseInt, Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

This method has a `Collector` paramter, to define the returned type, in addition to the input and mapper functions.

Comment: “Shorthand”…writing `mapApply(numbersAsString, Integer::parseInt, Collectors.toList())` instead of `numbersAsString.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList())`…

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/) which has a rich API directly on collections with covariant return types for methods like `collect` (aka `map`).

For example:

```
MutableList<Foo> fooList;
MutableList<Bar> barList = fooList.collect(Foo::bar);

MutableSet<Foo> fooSet;
MutableSet<Bar> barSet = fooSet.collect(Foo::bar);

MutableBag<Foo> fooBag;
MutableBag<Bar> barBag = fooBag.collect(Foo::bar);
```

The [`Iterate`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/10.4.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/utility/Iterate.html) utility class will also work with any `Iterable` and provides a rich set of protocols.

```
Iterable<Foo> fooIterable;
List<Bar> barList = Iterate.collect(fooIterable, Foo::bar, new ArrayList<>());
Set<Bar> barSet = Iterate.collect(fooIterable, Foo::bar, new HashSet<>());
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.